# Java write hashmap into file

Tags: java

Here is a method:

```
private void writeToFile() {
    try {
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String name = "dictionaryFile" + time + ".txt";
        File dictionaryFile = new File(name);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dictionaryFile));
        Iterator<String> it = dictionary.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            String line = it.next();
            String entryLine = line + " -> " + dictionary.get(line);
            writer.write(entryLine);
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here is error:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at WordQuizz.WordCollection.writeToFile(WordCollection.java:58)
at WordQuizz.WordCollection.actionPerformed(WordCollection.java:44)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? if I just try to sysout print entryLine then there is no error. May be I need to specify file location or something like this??

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have `writer.close();` inside the `while` loop.  Once it's closed on the first iteration, nothing else can be written, and the exception you saw is thrown.

Place the call to `close` after the `while` loop.  If you are using Java 7+, then use the ["try-with-resources" syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to have it closed when the `try` ends.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you closing your stream right in the middle of your while loop?  Rather:

```
while (it.hasNext()){
            String line = it.next();
            String entryLine = line + " -> " + dictionary.get(line);
            writer.write(entryLine);
}

writer.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not close the writer in middle of while loop. Change your code as below.

```
private void writeToFile() {
    BufferedWriter writer;
    try {
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String name = "dictionaryFile" + time + ".txt";
        File dictionaryFile = new File(name);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dictionaryFile));
        Iterator<String> it = dictionary.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String line = it.next();
            String entryLine = line + " -> " + dictionary.get(line);
            writer.write(entryLine);
            //writer.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       if (writer != null) {
           writer.close();
       }
    }
}
```

Always close the IO operation in finally block, and check if instance is not null.